# How to click on this button using webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to click on this button on this code the probleme in the href it change each time so I can't find it by href link and for the text in button i used

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='VÃ©rifier Maintenant']").click()
```

```
<a href="https://www.majilan-sev.com/finalization&amp;token=a2PrzORvYmkxM0BmbGFzaG1haWwuY28=" target="_blank">
<button style="position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 7px 12px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif;
  transition: all .2s;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: .2px;
  border: none !important;
  outline: none !important;"type="button"
name="button">VÃ©rifier Maintenant</button>
</a>
```

Here is the error that I got :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='VÃ©rifier Maintenant']").click()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[text()='V\xe9rifier Maintenant']"}
  (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.103)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64)
```

Comment: The button has a `name` attribute... have you tried using it? Either `.find_element_by_name("button")` or `.find_element_by_css_selector("[name='button']")` should work.

Comment: @JeffC Please take some time to read the _placeholder_ text within the _comment box_ which explicitly mentions to **avoid answering questions in comments**.

Comment: @DebanjanB If you read my comment, you would see it's a question... note the placement of the "?" at the end. OP only showed one attempt and I was asking if she had tried a few other options that were simpler than the proposed answers.

Comment: @JeffC As a community member we all know your habit of constructing answers clubbing up the comments from discussions. Moving forward please _avoid answering questions in comments_.

Comment: @DebanjanB If that *were* true, I'm sure you would have let me know about long ago... please stop inventing things and move on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this selector.

```
//button[contains(text(),'rifier Maintenant')]
```

try not to use special characters in selectors, most of the times they just don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Following [selenium documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath) their example looks like:

```
username = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']")
```

So i imagine in your situation it would look like:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@name='button']").click()
```

Since the name is "button" and the type is also a `<button>` HTML element. I believe you are confusing another method that would search by the link text. Specifically

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('some link text')
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Button name is unique, then this xpath will be enough :

```
//button[@name='button']
```

otherwise you can use this one :

```
//button[@name='button' and contains(text(),'rifier Maintenant')]
```